# nginx ignoring server block to replace the default root page

Tags: nginx

this is my nginx config, when I go on the server and do `curl localhost` I just see the default nginx page. I have a server block for "/" on port 80 but its being ignored.

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
  worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
  include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type  application/octet-stream;
  log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                    '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                    '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
  sendfile        on;
  #tcp_nopush     on;
  keepalive_timeout  65;
  #gzip  on;
  include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

  server {
    # expose /nginx_status but on a different port to avoid
    # external visibility / conflicts with the app.
    listen 8090;
    listen [::]:8090;

    location / {
      root /dev/null;
    }
    location /nginx_status {
      stub_status on;
      access_log off;
    }
  }

  server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    location / {
      root /var/http/test.html;
      index test.html;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: hows about `nginx -T|more`? and paste the output

Comment: ah i see this which is likely mucking things up, how do I disable the default config? `# configuration file /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:`

Comment: move it out of that directory? mv file /root or so? ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can add `server_name localhost;` in your `server` block you added, then the request won't hit the `default_server` block.

In general, one should always specify `server_name` in nginx.

Answer (score 0):

i belive that your running a `default. conf` on
`include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;`

you may check that with `nginx -T | more`

to disable this file just move it with `mv /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf /root` and then reload by `service nginx reload`

hope it helps

Comment: @red888 is your question solved?